# Large memory consumption upon loading model

Tags: mesh, memory-management, stl

When I import a single large STL (700MB), Blender uses 3GB of memory. This is before any operations have been performed. While editing, the memory consumption jumps to 16GB and my computer grinds to a halt. Is there any way that I can reduce the amount of RAM required by Blender if I'm not using any textures / sculpting / etc and just doing mesh operations?

Comment: can you have a look at your statistics and tell me how many vertices and faces your viewport is currently handling , also try hiding your model to see if it improves , just to make sure that the model is the root cause